# How to redirect cloud distribution URL to custom URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a cloudfront distribution i.e. d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net and I am using ALB as my custom origin.

Need is to point https://abc.example.com/claims to my cloudfront distribution so that users should use https://abc.example.com/claims to access the content from load balancer via cloudfront.
Kindly advise how can I achieve this thing.

Comment: what is the problem ? You just need a CNAME for abc.example.com to  d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net  or optional alias record if it's route53. if you just want that /claims should go by cloudfront, it's not possible, a browser doesn't consider path , just the host.

Comment: Requirement is that user should get the application content from cloudfront using https://abc.examole.com/claims .

Comment: My origin is ALB , so I am still wondering how to add that /claims after the cname abc.example.com in cloudfront .

Comment: Did you try to put the app behind de ALB under the path /claims instead of being in the root path?

Comment: My service is working on fargate